# Printing literal '\n' in nested print statements in bash

Tags: bash, unix

Got an interesting situation here, would appreciate any help.  My command is the following:

```
awk '{
where = match(somecondition)
if (where)
{
print "printf \"printf \"Hello...\n\" >> finalscript.sh\" >> intermediaryscript.sh"
}
}
1'
```

Execution of this command should add a line to the intermediaryscript such that, upon intermediaryscript's execution, the following line should be added to the end of finalscript.sh **literally** as shown here:

```
printf "Hello...\n" >> finalscript.sh
```

So, I've tried escaping \n with as many as up to 7 backslashes in the first command above to try to just get the darn thing to print a literal \n all the way down to this level, but no luck.  It either results in a newline render at the intermediaryscript or the finalscript level.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?  It'd be awfully nice to be able to enforce a literal print of anything and completely ignore the \n and instead just treat \ and n as two separate characters placed next to each other.

Thanks!

Comment: Executing that awk script can't be appending to either of those files. Do you mean you want it to spit out a line that when run appends to `intermediaryscript.sh` which when, itself, run spits out that inner line to `finalscript.sh`? Quoting quotes is somewhat horribly fractal.

Comment: Yep, incredibly fractal, no disagreements there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
awk '{
where = match(somecondition)
if (where)
{
print "printf \"printf \\\\\\\"Hello...\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\" >> finalscript.sh\" >> intermediaryscript.sh"
}
}
1'
```

Comment: Wow you nailed it.  Never in a million years could I have figured this one out.

Comment: @CAPGuy Built it up from the inside out and carefully watched the output at each stage. I could not explain to you why this is what you needed if you paid me to. (I'm sure I could figure it out but I don't know offhand.)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo | awk '{print "printf \"printf \\\"Hello...\\\\n\\\"\" >> finalscript.sh" >> "intermediaryscript.sh"}'
```